# Why is this the solution?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have this exercise with the solution.

Let $X\sim N(0,1)$.  Show that $P(2X = 3Y + 1) = 0$ if $Y\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$.

I have this solution

$P(2X=3Y+1)= P(\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}(2X = 3Y+1, Y=k)) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(2X=3Y+1, Y=k) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(2X=3k+1, Y=k)< \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(2X=3k+1) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X = \frac{3k+1}{2})=0$.

but I don't understand because $\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X = \frac{3k+1}{2})$ is zero.

Thanks to all!

Comment: I don't think there is anything to show here.  $X$ is continuous, so the probability that it equals anything is zero.  If you need an argument then $P(2X = 3Y + 1) = \text{E}[P(2X = 3Y + 1 | Y)] = \text{E}(0) = 0$ should be enough.

Comment: @dsaxton I would consider this as an answer is there any reason why you haven't?

Comment: Even simpler: $\frac12\mathbb N$ is countable hence $P(X\in\frac12\mathbb N)=0$, and $[2X=3Y+1]\subseteq[X\in\frac12\mathbb N]$.